# XSP Starter Kit based project doesnt run on Domino server

Tags: xpages

Based on excellent Tim Tripcony video http://notesin9.com/index.php/2012/04/04/notesin9-064-global-custom-controls-fixed/ on XSP Starter Kit subject. I created everything according to video, in Designer R9 the control is available and no errors there. Now when deployed to Domino server (R9) using updateSite database, deployment was succesfull, I can see it in the list of OSGi plugins but when I open any xpage in database, where this Starter Kit library is enabled, any xpage fails with Error 500 and in the log I can see the following error:

```
<extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceClassName" type="string">
    <values>com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager</values>
</extendedDataElements>
<extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceMethodName" type="string">
    <values>service</values>
</extendedDataElements>
<extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:Exception" type="string">
    <values>java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoFacesContext&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.initModule(ComponentModule.java:461)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.initModule(NSFComponentModule.java:498)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.createNSFModule(NSFService.java:752)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.loadModule(NSFService.java:735)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:588)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManage</values>
    <values>r.java:272)&#xD;&#xA;Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoFacesContext&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.CLBootStrap.initContext(CLBootStrap.java:89)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.BootStrap.init(BootStrap.java:82)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.ConfigureCoreListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureCoreListener.java:39)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.initModule(ComponentModule.java:453)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;... 8 more&#xD;&#xA;Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoFacesContext&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:287)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:165)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:557)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclip</values>
    <values>se.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:527)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:458)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:446)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:426)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:193)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:370)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:446)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.int</values>
    <values>ernal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:433)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:351)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:589)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:483)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:276)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.verifyFactories(ConfigureListener.java:1045)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:422)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.CLBootStrap.initContext(CLBootStrap.java:81)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;... 11 more&#xD;&#xA;Caused by: java.lang.</values>
    <values>ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoFacesContext&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:483)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;... 36 more&#xD;&#xA;</values>
</extendedDataElements>
<sourceComponentId component="Expeditor 6.2" componentIdType="ProductName" instanceId="" location="dmhp" locationType="Hostname" subComponent="" threadId="1" componentType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
<situation categoryName="ReportSituation">
    <situationType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ReportSituation" reasoningScope="INTERNAL" reportCategory="LOG"/>
</situation>
```

I tried to build everything several times with the same result. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: The source of your class might help. Looks like a class loader / class path / permission error

Comment: What class do you mean? The traceback says it cant load some basic XSP core classes. But its XSP Starter Kit project without any change. I have also granted all permissions in java.policy .

Answer (score 0):

You have to put com.ibm.xsp.domino on library dependencies. Just it.